# How to test Spring boot OAuth2 authorization code flow Using SoapUI

Tags: spring-boot, google-oauth, spring-oauth2

I have made a sample spring boot project that secures the urls using OAuth2 with google login.
The application is working fine on localhost:8080. The login page at http://localhost:8080/login correctly shows Google login option and allows me to login using my google account. Once logged in, the application redirects the browser to http://localhost:8080/list and shows some data.

Now, I am trying to test the application by sending the same GET request using SoapUI.
I am able to get the Auth Token using Soap UI but I am not sure where to put this token (in Header tab or in Auth tab) and which URL should I send this token to?

My understanding is that I should be able to get an Auth Code from google and then send that Auth Code to my application url /login/oauth2/code/google But I am not getting Auth Code. I am getting Auth Token.
[image: Getting Auth Token]

What am I doing wrong?

thank you.
Also, I couldn't find the default end point urls used by Spring boot. All the examples available on the net just assume that it works out of the box but I couldn't find the exact urls for the endpoints.